# Azure Active Directory Powershell Management

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

**Code:**

`$GroupObjectID = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" | select ObjectId`

`Write-Output $GroupObjectID`

`Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $GroupObjectID`

**Output:**

> ObjectId
> -------- a0xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
>
> Get-AzureADGroup : Error occurred while executing GetGroup Code:
> Request_BadRequest Message: Invalid object identifier
> '@{ObjectId=a0xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx}'. RequestId:
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx DateTimeStamp: Fri, 26 Nov 2021
> 14:56:43 GMT HttpStatusCode: BadRequest HttpStatusDescription: Bad
> Request HttpResponseStatus: Completed At line:1 char:1
>
> - Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $DecryptGroupObjectID
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADGroup], ApiException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetGroup
>   ```

Question: The write-output statement gives me an ObjectID back, I store this and in the next line query a group that matches this objectid. I assume I store a system.object instead of a system.String, but how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did try with below PowerShell Script and getting the expected output you are looking for

```
$GroupObjectID = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "'Merican Numero Uno"
Write-Output $GroupObjectID
Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $GroupObjectID.ObjectId
```

[image]
OR

```
$GroupObjectID = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "'Merican Numero Uno" |select ObjectId,DisplayName,Description
Write-Output $GroupObjectID
Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $GroupObjectID.ObjectId
```

[image]

Reason for why your Script was not working because first line of script is only taking the `objectID` in the variable and expecting to print the `DisplayName`. As `$GroupObjectID` variable has three different Value ie `ObjectID`,`DisplayName`,`Description` so you have to pass the all the argument which you want to display.

```
$GroupObjectID = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" | select ObjectId
```